# How do i find the average of a multi-dimensional list?

Tags: python, list, average

I am looking to find the average 'total' for test scores of the class. i run my program but keep getting "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'".

```
def newRecord(students,tests):
  students = int(input('How many students are in your class? '))
  tests = int(input('How many tests have you given? '))

  record = []
   for i in range(students):
    rec_line = []
   for j in range(tests+1):
    rec_line.append(0)
   record.append(rec_line)
  print('record:',record)
  print('modified record:',record)

  for A in range (students):
     record[A][0] = input('Please enter student {} name '.format(A+1))
    for B in range (1, tests+1):
        record[A][B] = input ('Please enter test score  {} '.format(B))
  print (record)

  total= float(sum(record))/ len(record)
  print ('Average is: ',total )
```

Comment: Currently it looks like the function `newRecord` has only two lines, which I doubt. Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Which line gives you `TypeError`?

Comment: You're putting the names of students in this list and trying to add the whole list up. How do you expect that to work? You're also forgetting to convert the score string to an int or float in `record[A][B] = input (...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each test result needs to be converted to an `int` or `float` in order to perform mathematical functions on them. In your example above you're also addressing the name of the student, which will thrown an error when you try and calculate an "average".

```
def newRecord(students,tests):
    students = int(input('How many students are in your class? '))
    tests = int(input('How many tests have you given? '))

record = []
for i in range(students):
    rec_line = []
    for j in range(tests+1):
        rec_line.append(0)
    record.append(rec_line)
print('record:',record)
print('modified record:',record)

for A in range (students):
    record[A][0] = input('Please enter student {} name '.format(A+1))
    for B in range (1, tests+1):
        record[A][B] = input ('Please enter test score  {} '.format(int(B)))
print(record)

total= sum([int(score) for score in rec[1:] for rec in record])/len([int(score) for score in rec[1:] for rec in record])
print('Average is: ',total )
```

Example usage:

```
record: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
modified record: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
Please enter student 1 name Alice
Please enter test score  1 2
Please enter test score  2 3
Please enter student 2 name Bob
Please enter test score  1 4
Please enter test score  2 5
[['Alice', '2', '3'], ['Bob', '4', '5']]
Average is:  3.5
```

Comment: I would also recommend using a better data structure for the scores, such as a dictionary that will allow you to address a list of results for a given student name. So, for example, in the usage above the dictionary could look like: `record = {"Alice": [2, 3], "Bob": [4, 5]}`. This could be a potential solution to what @Alex Hall  is remarking on above.